# The definite integral of $\int_0^u \ln(ax)/\sqrt{u-x}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I need to solve the integral:

$$\int_0^u \frac{\ln(ax)}{\sqrt{u-x}}\,dx$$

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? We ask that you show some effort so that we can help you better.

Comment: Please show some work, or let us, at the very least, know what integral strategies you are aware of (which you have tried using).

Comment: Since $$\int_{0}^u \frac{1}{\sqrt{u-x}} dx$$ is an elementary integral (perhaps surprisingly), we can use the laws of logarithms to get rid of the $a$ and just be dealing with $$\int_{0}^u \frac{\ln(x)}{\sqrt{u-x}} dx.$$

Comment: Yes @Chris ..I Have tried that .... Still not able to find the answer.

Comment: You may choose to let as few as possible parameters in your integral if it does not affect the generalization etc etc. I guess the one I wrote will attract more people.

Comment: @Shashi what substitution did you use to get to this form

Answer (score 2):

Let us assume
$$f(a) =\int_0^u \frac{\ln (ax)}{\sqrt{u-x}} \rm dx $$ Now we've $$f'(a)= \int_0^u \frac{1}{ax} \cdot \frac{ x}{\sqrt{u-x}} \rm dx \implies f'(a) = \frac 1a \int_0^u \frac{1}{\sqrt{u-x}} \rm dx$$

$$f'(a) =-\frac{2 \sqrt{u-x}}{a} \Bigg |_0^u=\frac{2\sqrt u} a$$

$$\implies f(a) = \int \frac{2\sqrt u}{a}  \rm da = 2\sqrt u (\ln (a)+C)$$

You can find $C$ by using some intial conditions. Note that $C$ can depend on $u$ only, not on $a$)

Comment: You are missing an integration constant, which renders your result incorrect.

Comment: @pisco125 Thanks for suggestion. Fixed it. BTW, I haven't arrived to the correct answer yet. Do you have any ideas for finding $C$?

Comment: @JaideepKhare Thanks a lot sir...... The correct answer as perr mathematica is : $2\sqrt{u}(-2+ln(4au))$   I really dont know, how they arrive the answer, but yours is very close. I really want to know ,how they arrived at this answer, that is the reason why I asked this question here. anyways thanks a lot sir